# ask how to delete all right text after containing Colon (:) in EMEDITOR?

Tags: regex, text-editors

I want delete all right text after character Colon (:)

---

example :

```
user1@mail.com:pass
user2@mail.com:psword
user3@mail.com:pasword123
user4@mail.com:@*!@$Haslkf
```

---

delete after character Colon (:)

---

results :

```
user1@mail.com:
user2@mail.com:
user3@mail.com:
user4@mail.com:
```

please dont use other product , I just want emeditor.

Thanks

https://www.emeditor.com/

Comment: Uh.... make selection, press delete?

Comment: Please clarify what you want as it's not clear. Do you want to delete all characters on each line after a specified character? All characters on a line after position _n_? Please click [edit] and improve the question so it's unmistakably clear to any reader of this site. Also, have you consulted their help forum site? https://www.emeditor.com/forums/

Comment: hello I already edit post sorry for bad english

Comment: If you only want a solution in emeditor why did you tag your question with two irrelevant text editors and "email filter"? I can tell you exactly how to do this in minimal steps in Notepad++ (one of your tags) without having to change every line one-by-one, but can't because you have explicitly said you don't want that solution in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want is to truncate the line after the colon, this is simple
using the option in the Replace dialog of Regular Expressions:

**Find:** `(.*:).*`
**Replace with:** `\1`